# I have to validate the time for 1 hr . Start and end time shud not be greater than 1 hr

Tags: html, angularjs

Trying to validate start and end time shud not be > than 1 hr.USing angular basic functionality for this validation.

Also trying to have date-picker but not happening for me as i am on private network.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope){
 $scope.valid = false;
 $scope.submit = function(){
  $scope.valid = true;
 }
 $scope.close = function(){
  $scope.valid = false;
 }
});
```

```html
Trying to validate start and end time shud not be > than 1 hr.USing angular basic functionality for this validation.

Also trying to have date-picker but not happening for me as i am on private network.

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="app">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>AngularJS Form Validation</title>
      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css">
        .errortext {
          color: red;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
// form start here
    <body ng-controller="myController">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div class=" form-body">
            <form role="form" name="myForm" novalidate>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label "> Gate Open Date </label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input name="gateOpenDate" class="form-control" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" ng-pattern="/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/" ng-model="addFlood.gateOpenDate" required autofocus/>
                  <div class="errortext" ng-show="myForm.gateOpenDate.$dirty && myForm.gateOpenDate.$invalid">
                    <span ng-show="myForm.gateOpenDate.$error.required">Gate Open Date is required</span>
                    <span ng-show="myForm.gateOpenDate.$error.pattern">Date Format Must Be DD/MM/YYYY</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"> </i>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
//start time
              <div class="form-group ">
                <label class="control-label "> Start Time </label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input name="startTime" class="form-control" placeholder="HH:MM " ng-pattern="/^([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)$/" min="addFlood.startTime" ng-model="addFlood.startTime" required/>
                  <div class="errortext" ng-show="myForm.startTime.$dirty && myForm.startTime.$invalid || myForm.endTime.$dirty && addFlood.startTime == addFlood.endTime">
                    <span ng-show="myForm.startTime.$error.required">Start Time is required</span>
                    <span ng-show="myForm.startTime.$error.pattern">Invalid Time Format</span>
                    <span ng-show="myForm.startTime.$error.min">Username must contain atleast 10 characters</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"> </i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
//end time
              <div class="form-group ">
                <label class="control-label ">End time </label>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input name="endTime" class="form-control" placeholder="HH:MM " ng-pattern="/^([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)$/" ng-max="addFlood.endTime" ng-model="addFlood.endTime" required/>
                  <div class="errortext" ng-show="myForm.endTime.$dirty && myForm.startTime.$invalid || myForm.endTime.$dirty && addFlood.startTime == addFlood.endTime || myForm.endTime.$dirty && addFlood.startTime-addFlood.endTime !=100">
                    <span ng-show="myForm.endTime.$error.required">Start Time is required</span>
                    <span ng-show="myForm.endTime.$error.pattern">Invalid Time Format</span>
                    <!--<span ng-show="!myForm.endTime.$error.required && addFlood.startTime = addFlood.endTime">Start and end time must not be same.</span>-->
                    <span ng-show="!myForm.endTime.$error.required && addFlood.endTime.diff(addFlood.startTime, 'hours')">Start and end time must same.</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"> </i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group ">
                <label class="control-label "> Number Of Orders </label>
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="addFlood.numberOfOrders" ng-pattern="/[0-9]+/" name="numberOfOrders" placeholder="Order #" required/>
                <div class="errortext" ng-show="myForm.numberOfOrders.$dirty && myForm.numberOfOrders.$invalid">
                  <span ng-show="myForm.numberOfOrders.$error.required">Order Number required</span>
                  <span ng-show="myForm.numberOfOrders.$error.pattern">Only Numbers are Allowed</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary " ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="addSdFloodInfo(addFlood, gatingDetil)" name="submit" type="submit">
                    Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

      <script src="angular.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Trying to validate start and end time shud not be > than 1 hr.USing angular basic functionality for this validation.

Also trying to have date-picker but not happening for me as i am on private network.

Comment: This will not solve your issue, but you ought to separate the validation logic from your view. Move it to your controller or a service instead. It will make it much easier to reason about what happens (and by extension, might get you an answer quicker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('myController', function($scope){
     $scope.valid = false;
     $scope.submit = function(){
      $scope.valid = true;
     }
     $scope.close = function(){
      $scope.valid = false;
     }
    });
    Trying to validate start and end time shud not be > than 1 hr.USing angular basic functionality for this validation.

    Also trying to have date-picker but not happening for me as i am on private network.

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en" ng-app="app">

        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>AngularJS Form Validation</title>
          <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
          <style type="text/css">
            .errortext {
              color: red;
            }
          </style>
        </head>
    // form start here
        <body ng-controller="myController">
         <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   <div class=" form-body">
    <form role="form" name="myForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label "> Gate Open Date </label>
     <div class="input-group">
      <input name="gateOpenDate" class="form-control" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" ng-pattern="/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/" ng-model="addFlood.gateOpenDate" required autofocus/>
      <div class="errortext" ng-show="myForm.gateOpenDate.$dirty && myForm.gateOpenDate.$invalid">
                <span ng-show="myForm.gateOpenDate.$error.required">Gate Open Date is required</span>
                <span ng-show="myForm.gateOpenDate.$error.pattern">Date Format Must Be DD/MM/YYYY</span>
               </div>
               <div class="input-group-addon">
       <i class="fa fa-calendar"> </i>
      </div>
               
     </div>
    </div>
    
     <div class="form-group " >
     <label class="control-label "> Start Time </label>
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="time" name="startTime" class="form-control" placeholder="HH:MM 24h format" ng-model="addFlood.startTime" required/>
      <div class="errortext" ng-show="myForm.startTime.$dirty && myForm.startTime.$invalid">
              <span ng-show="myForm.startTime.$error.required">Start Time is required</span>
                <span ng-show="myForm.startTime.$error.time">Invalid Time Format</span>
               </div>
      <div class="input-group-addon">
       <i class="fa fa-clock-o"> </i>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
            <div class="form-group " >
     <label class="control-label ">End time </label>
     <div class="input-group">
      <input type="time" name="endTime" class="form-control" placeholder="HH:MM 24h format" ng-model="addFlood.endTime" required/>
      <div class="errortext" ng-show="myForm.endTime.$dirty && myForm.endTime.$invalid || myForm.endTime.$dirty && ((addFlood.endTime-addFlood.startTime)/(1000*60*60) >1)">
              <span ng-show="myForm.endTime.$error.required">End Time is required</span>
                <span ng-show="myForm.endTime.$error.time">Invalid Time Format</span>
                <span ng-show="!myForm.endTime.$error.required && ((addFlood.endTime-addFlood.startTime)/(1000*60*60)>1)">Flood interval is greater than 1 Hr</span>
               </div>
      <div class="input-group-addon">
       <i class="fa fa-clock-o"> </i>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label "> Number Of Orders </label> 
      <input class="form-control" ng-model="addFlood.numberOfOrders" ng-pattern="/[0-9]+/" name="numberOfOrders" placeholder="Order #" required/>
      <div class="errortext" ng-show="myForm.numberOfOrders.$dirty && myForm.numberOfOrders.$invalid">
              <span ng-show="myForm.numberOfOrders.$error.required">Order Number required</span>
                <span ng-show="myForm.numberOfOrders.$error.pattern">Only Numbers are Allowed</span>
               </div>
     </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary " ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"
       ng-click="addSdFloodInfo(addFlood, gatingDetil)" name="submit" type="submit">
       Submit</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>

          <script src="angular.js"></script>
        </body>

        </html>
```

Comment: used input type="time" to get the difference between start and end time.

Answer (score 0):

use

`<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>`
then get difference between two timestamps with this method:

```
endTime.diff(startTime, 'hours')
```

afterward apply if-else with condition for more than one hour.
Here startTime and endTime two variables, that should be user defined.

**with pure javascript without momentJs cdn**:

hour difference could be concluded with this way:

```
function timeDifference(t1,t2) {
        var difference = t1.getTime() - t2.getTime();


       var hoursDifference = Math.floor(difference/1000/60/60);
        difference -= hoursDifference*1000*60*60
}
```

Comment: can you install npm for this